# jQuery focus is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to add focus function to my specific input i.e want to show a div on focus with class as : .search_by_name but it's not working so if you people please take a look at my code that what I am doing wrong please?

Here is code as :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.search_by_business_name {
    background: #474747;
    display: none;
    width: 297px;
    margin-left: 179px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}

.arrow-up_search_by_business_name {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #474747;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    left: 20px;
}

.search_by_business_name_text {
    background: #99cc33;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
</style>

<input type="text" class="search_input" id="search_by_business_name_input" placeholder="Hi Ruyben, what do you want to find today ?">

<div class="search_by_business_name"> 
<div class="arrow-up_search_by_business_name"></div><!-- end div arrow-up_search_by_business_name -->
<div class="search_by_business_name_text">Search by business name, or keyword</div><!-- end div search_by_business_name_text -->
</div><!-- end div search_by_business_name -->

<script>
$( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).focus(function() {
$( this ).next( ".search_by_business_name" ).css( "display", "block" );});
</script>
```

Please have a look at live version as : http://huntedhunter.com/waseem_jobs/pacific_site/index.html

Comment: how is the page loaded? is it using a web server(using http or https protocol) or from a local file system(using file protocol)

Comment: your code looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n9qu276q/2/

Comment: At localhost but I have included the jquery library..!

Comment: try changing `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` - it could be a problem with using relative protocol reference...

Comment: my jquery library at localhost is as : `<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: your code is working fine for me.... can you check whether the jQuery library is available in the correct path... check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: you have added the script after the end of `html` tag? move it above the `</body>`

Comment: I am not getting any erros in console..!

Comment: moved the script to head tag but still not working..!

Comment: Please have a look at live version as : http://huntedhunter.com/waseem_jobs/pacific_site/index.html

Comment: also `.search_by_business_name` is not a sibling of `#search_by_business_name_input`... so you need `$(".search_by_business_name" ).css( "display", "block" );`

Comment: Use `console.log` to check: element's length (ex: `console.log($( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).length)` and callback call

Comment: So what should I do please?

Comment: `console.log($( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).length)` give me `1`

Comment: @ArunPJohny : I have updated the code as but still not working as please : `$( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).focus(function() {function() { $(".search_by_business_name").css("display", "block");}, function() { $(".search_by_business_name").css("display", "");}});`

Comment: @SalmanKhan `$("#search_by_business_name_input").focus(function () {
    $(".search_by_business_name").show();
}).blur(function () {
    $(".search_by_business_name").hide();
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, you should not use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as the element you are looking for is not the next sibling of the target element.

Also [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) takes only one function as argument, you need to use [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) to hide the element

```
$("#search_by_business_name_input").focus(function () {
    $(".search_by_business_name").show();
}).blur(function () {
    $(".search_by_business_name").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with adding document.ready function too...! didn't work without document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

The script should be inside the `<body>` tag.
In your page the script is after `</body></html>`

```
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "#search_by_business_name_input" )
                .focus(function() {
                    $( ".search_by_business_name" ).show();
                })
                .blur(function() {
                    $( ".search_by_business_name" ).hide();
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Edit:

Of course it does not work.
Have you read the documentation for [$.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)?

#### .next()

`Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

Replace this:

```
$( this ).next( ".search_by_business_name" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

With:

```
$( ".search_by_business_name" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

### Edit2:

Wrap your code in $.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#search_by_business_name_input" )
        .focus(function() {
            $( ".search_by_business_name" ).show();
        })
        .blur(function() {
            $( ".search_by_business_name" ).hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code as but still not working please as : `$( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).focus(function() {function() { $(".search_by_business_name").css("display", "block");}, function() { $(".search_by_business_name").css("display", "");}});`

Comment: Have a look at live link please as : http://huntedhunter.com/waseem_jobs/pacific_site/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
<script>

    $( "#search_by_business_name_input" ).focus(function() {
      $( ".search_by_business_name" ).show();
    });

</script>
```

at the bottom of body element, because when excute this code,

```
$("#search_by_business_name_input" ) = []
```

or

you can write it like this

```
$(document).on("focus", "#search_by_business_name_input", function(){
  $( ".search_by_business_name" ).show();
})
```